# Access denied for user 'john'@'gateway' (using password: NO) MARIA DB

Tags: linux, mysql, remote-access, mariadb

My os are linux. I got denied to access db server from web server. I have built database with name is **test**. I also already created user with name **'john'@'10.0.0.1'** with password **'pass'** and set all privileges to the database **test**.

For another information, my bind-ip is:

- 10.0.0.2

My db server has ip static with:

- ip: 10.0.0.2
- netmask: 255.0.0.0
- gw : 10.0.0.1

My web server has ip static too with:

- ip: 10.0.0.1
- netmask: 255.0.0.0
- gw : 10.0.0.100

Is it something wrong with my db configuration or my network configuration because i got output **Access denied for user 'john'@'gateway' (using password: NO)?**

Comment: You create a username and set a password and then your client returns as part of the error: "using password: NO" - Have you tried to configure your client to **connect with a passsword**? ???

Answer (score 0):

Run this privilege statement on MySQL database and try connecting again. Please let me know what happens next.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'john'@'10.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;


FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```